# Mysql Trigger to insert the last date

Tags: mysql, date, triggers

I have to make only one insertion / day on a Mysql table .

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trig
BEFORE INSERT ON Table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
/** compare the date with the latest inserted **/
  IF () THEN
    // if it's ok => insert
  ELSE
    // nothing
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I want to compare the last inserted date and current date and then initiate my trigger to do the work.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you don't need any of those messy `<br />` tags, either!

Comment: Do you need to insert first record or last in a day?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without trigger (which is a good thing right?) by creating a `UNIQUE` constraint on the date column and then using `INSERT IGNORE` syntax.

Suppose you have a table with the following schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  date DATE, 
  value INT
);
```

Let's create a UNIQUE constraint

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_date_unique ON table1 (date);
```

Now you can use `IGNORE` clause

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 VALUES (CURDATE(), 1);
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 VALUES (CURDATE(), 2);
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 VALUES (CURDATE(), 3);
```

As a result you'll have only first row in the table for each day.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3a88/1)** demo